# Broken trust relationship not corrected even after leaving and joining domain with new computer name

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am having a problem with a recently reinstalled laptop with Win 7 Enterprise. The computer is complaining about a broken trust relationship when I try to grant domain users local access on the machine.

I've done the following (twice, using a different name each time) and it doesn't resolve the issue:

1. As domain administrator, leave domain and join workgroup: WORKGROUP.
2. Reboot.
3. As domain administrator, join domain using new computer name.
4. Reboot.
5. As domain administrator, add a domain user as local administrator.
6. Error: "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

This doesn't make any sense to me. As I understand it the above process is the appropriate way to fix this issue.

So far, other symptoms I've experienced are:

The client machine says it's unable to reach the domain.  Meanwhile, on the server, I see EventID 5723 from NETLOGON:

`The session setup from the computer [name_of_computer] failed because there is no trust account in the security database for this computer. The name of the account referenced in the security database is [name_of_computer]$.`

An inability to to ping hosts by hostname when joined to the domain.  When off the domain, I can ping hosts just fine.

`nslookup [fqdn]` returns the proper value for both my domain controllers, and `nsloookup [DC hostname]` returns the proper IP for the domain controller as well.

I've checked to see that the DNS servers are being assigned properly to the clients, and they are.

I also don't believe I have any WINS servers handing out incorrect NS information.  Neither Domain Controller has that role installed (though if anyone has a definitive way to check for WINS servers, that might be helpful).

Can anyone provide some further troubleshooting steps?

Comment: what do you see in the event logs on both the dc and the workstation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 Trust issues](http://serverfault.com/questions/400252/windows-7-trust-issues)

Comment: @MDMarra I don't believe so. The accepted answer in that post does not apply here. (1) I am using computer names that didn't previously exist, (2) time is not out of sync, and (3) I have only one site and I am operating locally. Let me know if you think otherwise though because I just want to get this resolved.

Comment: You asked for basic troubleshooting steps. They're the same steps. You can still have replication problems in a single site, I'd start there.

Comment: @MDMarra Not sure how you're coming to that conclusion. I actually asked for "further troubleshooting steps". Thanks though!

Comment: so prior to re joining the domain if you do a "nslookup fqdn" what results do you get?

Comment: @tonyroth I get the expected IP address and information returned. I'm currently reading everything I can about this issue but after several forums I have not found a clear answer.

Comment: so you get a list of ip addresses of your domain controllers, correct?

Comment: @tonyroth Yes. The normal output: a Server and Address pair (DNS server that was used) and a Name and Address pair (host being looked up).

Comment: do you have more then one dc?

Comment: Yes, two total.

Comment: ok so the nslookup fqdn shows both dc's ipaddresses correct? Hate asking these things sound trivial to me but... Also after joining the domain what happens when you do a nslookup fqdn?

Comment: No. Maybe I didn't state it well before but there are only 4 lines of output: Server+Address (DNS server used to do lookup) and Name+Address (host being looked up). This is how nslookup behaves on all my machines. Do you see something different? The computer having the problem is currently joined to the domain.

Comment: so doing an nslookup yourdomain.com does not show a list of your dc's?

Comment: I'm sorry but I thought you meant the FQDN of a host on the network. I apologize for not picking that up. I do in fact see both DNS server IP addresses when I look up my domain.

Comment: do you have an active wins servers thats handing out the wrong results?

Comment: I don't believe so. That role is not installed on either DC.

Comment: so prior to joining the domain do a ping dchostname and post join to the same ping  are the ip addresses being ping the same?

Comment: I left the domain and ping worked fine on every host I tried (as expected). After rejoining the domain ping doesn't work at all: "Ping request could not find host dc-02. Please check the name and try again." This OS came from an image I used on 4 other identical laptops and this is the only one with this problem. I think I will reinstall Windows from scratch and see what happens. I thank you for your time in this.

Comment: Does ping work if you use an IP address instead of a DNS name?

Comment: This question is accumulating enough comments trying to diagnose what's going on that it's actually tripping automated alarms. That's a good sign that it's insufficiently detailed for us to help you figure out what to do, and needs a rewrite. Please consolidate all the relevant information gained thus far into the question, then let me know, and I will clear the comment history and re-open the question to give it another shot at getting a useful answer.

Comment: @voretaq7 Please go ahead and close the question. Unfortunately it's turned into a different beast than I originally thought so I'll just start a whole new question if I need to. Thanks!

Comment: when you do an ipconfig /all it will show the list the wins servers,  I'd think that you are probably correct in that you don't have any!  This is one of things that if I was on site I'd have solved in minutes at most, its just hard to see things via a forum!

Answer (score 1):

Your next troubleshooting step is to examine the DC EventLogs for anything useful, and following that, you'll want to figure out why the computer can't "reach the domain."

You might want to reverse the order of those, and they might lead you to the same spot, but looking for errors in the EventLog is usually easier than troubleshooting your network, which is why I'd recommend starting there.

Incidentally, if the computer can't "reach the domain," how are you able to join it to the domain at all?  Sounds to me like it's not properly joining to the domain, which is why the trust relationship is still broken.  Haven't seen that before, honestly... but you could try changing its name when it's domain-joined to test that idea.  See if the name changes in ADUC, or not (and see if it changes on all your DCs, or not - maybe there's a replication problem that's preventing the domain from recognizing the new computer account).  While you're in there, you might want to check and make sure the various computer accounts you created when "rejoining" it actually show up in AD.  I'm betting they didn't.

Comment: I left and rejoined the domain again using the latest computer name. That process went without a problem. Now being back on the domain I am no longer able to ping hosts. As you asked, how can I not ping hosts but I can authenticated against the DC to leave and rejoin the domain? I don't know but it's certainly not a physical disconnect in the network. The computer account appears in DNS and AD. I am unable to rename the computer because "network path not found" which is likely a result of the lack of connectivity in DNS. Lastly, both DCs have no errors for this computer (as of the last join).

Comment: Sounds like you have a GPO setting the client DNS servers to the wrong value.

Comment: @MDMarra I checked that early on but the DNS servers seen by ipconfig /all are correct.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely sounds like a DNS error.  Does nslookup return the correct value for your domain controller?  (And the DC's hostname isn't longer than 15 characters, is it?)

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yes, it does. I'm googling for this symptom but haven't found a resolution yet. It's definitely very strange.

Comment: @cparker4486:  Have you even seen any other people with the same symptoms, and non-obvious causes?  Maybe MDMarra's could help you with "edge-case" causes for this behavior... I've been lucky that when I run into an edge case with this behavior, it's long-past time to rebuild the domain anyway.  Probably won't help you much.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't even ping after joining the domain, the problem is somewhere in the networking stack and has nothing to do with the trust relationship per se.  (This means the usual troubleshooting steps for trust relationship errors, such as rejoining the domain, don't apply.)

My bet is that the Windows Firewall domain settings are messed up.  To confirm this, turn Windows Firewall off (**briefly!**) and see if that lets you ping.  If it does, check the settings, or try using the "Restore Defaults" option in the Windows Firewall control panel.

Comment: Windows firewall won't have anything to do with this.  Since most of these domain functions he's talking about use name resolution (NETBIOS or DNS), that's where he needs to look, and the usual troubleshooting step do apply... at least in a normalish AD environment.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: I don't see how you can rule out a problem with Windows Firewall.  He doesn't appear to have any network connectivity at all, and Windows Firewall could certainly do that if it was configured to block outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the box that says "Change primary DNS suffix when the domain membership changes"?

Answer (score -1):

1. update the drivers on the local workstation NIC
2. then delete the computer out of AD refresh
3. then re add to the Domain...

If that doesn't work, check GPO next.